# URL detection and shortening in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I was just wondering if there is a way in Django to detect URLs from a bunch of text and then shorten them up automatically. I know I can use urlize to detect urls, but I am not sure if I can use maybe bitly or something to shorten the links.

And also would it be better to accomplish this task with javascript instead of python? and if that is the case how do I go about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For bit.ly if you just want to shorten URLs, its quite simple:

First create an account, and then visit http://bitly.com/a/your_api_key to get your API key.

Send a request to the [shorten method](http://dev.bitly.com/links.html) of the API, the result is your shortened URL:

```
from urllib import urlencode
from urllib2 import urlopen

ACCESS_KEY = 'blahblah'
long_url = 'http://www.example.com/foo/bar/zoo/hello/'
endpoint = 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token={0}&longUrl={1}&format=txt'
req = urlencode(endpoint.format(ACCESS_KEY, long_url))
short_url = urlopen(req).read()
```

You can wrap that up into a template tag:

```
@register.simple_tag
def bitlyfy(the_url):
    endpoint = 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token={0}&longUrl={1}&format=txt'
    req = urlencode(endpoint.format(settings.ACCESS_KEY, the_url))
    return urlopen(req).read()
```

Then in your template:

`{% bitlyfy "http://www.google.com" %}`

*Note: Positional arguments in tags are a feature of django 1.4*

If you want the all the features of the bit.ly API, start by reading the documentation at [dev.bitly.com/get_started.html](http://dev.bitly.com/get_started.html), and then download the official [python client](https://github.com/bitly/bitly-api-python).

Comment: but what if I have a whole paragraph of text entered by the user, and the paragraph has some URL in it. So I want the URL to be detected automatically, and then shortened. would bit.ly do all of it?

Comment: No, you'd have to modify your template tag - or maybe write a template context processor - to search through the text; identify links, and then shorten them through bit.ly. You can use the source of the [urlize tag](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/html.py#L171) to get the "search for URLs in text" functionality.

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you again, but I tried to write a custom template tag for bitly but it doesnt seem to work. I've defined the problem more in detail [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134927/could-not-parse-the-remainder-django)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Bitly API the template tag should become:

```
from django import template from django.conf import settings

import bitly_api import sys import os

register = template.Library()

BITLY_ACCESS_TOKEN="blahhhh"

@register.simple_tag def bitlyfy(the_url):
    bitly = bitly_api.Connection(access_token=BITLY_ACCESS_TOKEN)
    data = bitly.shorten(the_url)
    return data['url']
```

There is one thing I couldn't manage in my template though:

```
{% bitlyfy request.get_full_path %}
{% bitlyfy {{request.get_full_path}} %}
```

Neither of those works, not sure how to solve it.
Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

```
If you are using bit.ly then the best code to shorten url is:

import urllib
import urllib2
import json


link = "http://www.example.com/foo/bar/zoo/hello/"
values = {'access_token' : BITLY_ACCESS_TOKEN,
          'longUrl'      : link}
url = "https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten"

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url,data)
response = (urllib2.urlopen(req).read()).replace('\/', '/')
bitly_url = (json.loads(response))['data']['url']
return bitly_url
```