# Could not parse the remainder Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I've been trying to write a custom template tag to shorten links with bitly, I've attached the code and error I've been getting below. I've tried to look into the documentation provided by Django but cannot see what it is that I am doing wrong.

I've put my templatetag in the following layout:

```
scribbler/
    models.py
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        shortenlink.py
    views.py
```

the custom tag file that I've written:

## shortenlink.py

```
from django import template
from django.conf import settings
from urllib import urlencode
from urllib2 import urlopen

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def bitlyshort(the_url):
    endpoint = 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token={0}&longUrl={1}&format=txt'
    req = urlencode(endpoint.format(settings.ACCESS_KEY, the_url))
    return urlopen(req).read()
```

part of the template that uses the template tag:

## template

```
{% load shortenlink %}
<p>{{ bitlyshort "http://www.google.com" }}</p>
```

## error

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /user/sankaetp/
Could not parse the remainder: ' "http://www.google.com"' from 'bitlyshort "http://www.google.com"'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/user/sankaetp/
Django Version: 1.4.1
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Could not parse the remainder: ' "http://www.google.com"' from 'bitlyshort "http://www.google.com"'
Exception Location: /Users/sankaetp/virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in __init__, line 563
Python Executable:  /Users/sankaetp/virtualenvs/myproject/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['/Users/sankaetp/virtualenvs/myproject/bin/django_worksquid',
 '/Users/sankaetp/virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg',
 '/Users/sankaetp/virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/Users/sankaetp/virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangoembed-0.1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/Users/sankaetp/virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.7.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/Users/sankaetp/virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/BeautifulSoup-3.2.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/Users/sankaetp/virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python27.zip',
 '/Users/sankaetp/virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7',
 '/Users/sankaetp/virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/Users/sankaetp/virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/Users/sankaetp/virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Users/sankaetp/virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/Users/sankaetp/virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/Users/sankaetp/virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/sankaetp/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7',
 '/Users/sankaetp/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/Users/sankaetp/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/Users/sankaetp/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/Users/sankaetp/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Users/sankaetp/virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/Users/sankaetp/virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL']
Server time:    Sun, 26 Aug 2012 18:54:26 -0500
```

Comment: In my case forgetting the colon `:` after the `date` filter: `{{ somedate | date:"Y m d" }}` caused this error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is on this line:

```
<p>{{ bitlyshort "http://www.google.com" }}</p>
```

Template *tags* use `{% ... %}` (template *filters* use `{{ ... }}`). Try:

```
<p>{% bitlyshort "http://www.google.com" %}</p>
```

Comment: I tried that too, but I keep on getting 
" Invalid block tag: 'bitlyshort', expected 'empty' or 'endfor' " 
error

Comment: @sankaet: Sounds like you have a malformed `for` tag in the template somewhere.

Comment: @mipadi is right. For your second error, check the the rest of the template file, you're probably forgetting to end a for loop. Also make sure, your app is listed in the [INSTALLED_APPS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-INSTALLED_APPS) settings.

Comment: yes Rahul, it is in the installed_apps.

@mipadi I just ended up adding the bitly api into django's urlize function and it works just fine after that :) thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

#### There is an alternative way to cause this error:

Instead of:

```
{{ data|filter }}
```

If you use:

```
{{ data | filter }}  <!-- Note Spaces -->
```

The spaces on either side of the `|` character will cause an exception during page render.

Comment: Spaces there don't seem to cause an issue.  What _does_ cause an issue is putting a space before the filter parameter like `x | date: "D"`.  you have to use `date:"D"`