# How to ignore the first item in a list in a FOR function?

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I have the following `for` loop that spits out all photos in a list:

```
{% if photos %}
{% for photo in photos %}
    {% thumbnail photo.photo "100x100" crop="center" as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}" alt="User's photos" data-ajax="{% url 'photo_increase_view' pk=photo.id %}"/>
    {% endthumbnail %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

**How can edit this to ignore the first result in the list (i.e. display items 2, 3, 4... etc)**

Comment: Do you want to do with jinja or django ? Both haven't the same best way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [`forloop.first` using Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for); for example:

```
{% if photos %}

    {% for photo in photos %}
        {% if not forloop.first %}
            {% thumbnail photo.photo "100x100" crop="center" as im %}
            <img src="{{ im.url }}" alt="User's photos" data-ajax="{% url 'photo_increase_view' pk=photo.id %}"/>
            {% endthumbnail %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`slice`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice)

Replace

```
{% for photo in photos %}
```

by

```
{% for photo in photos|slice:"1:" %}
```

So , complete code

```
{% if photos %}
{% for photo in photos|slice:"1:" %}
    {% thumbnail photo.photo "100x100" crop="center" as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}" alt="User's photos" data-ajax="{% url 'photo_increase_view' pk=photo.id %}"/>
    {% endthumbnail %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This results in `Could not parse the remainder: '[1:]' from 'photos[1:]'`

Comment: May be this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134927/could-not-parse-the-remainder-django

Comment: django template lists are not indexed like this, if you want to access the first object in a list it would be `{{photos.0}}` not sure how to do more complex slicing directly in the template. I would have dropped off the first photo in the view, personally

Comment: Can you try `for photo in photos|slice:"1:"` and reply if it works for you.

Answer (score 4):

I guess the answer it's a bit late. But a solution is:

```
{% for photo in photos[1:] %}
.....
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is perfect using jinja2; the solution `slice:"1:"` only works for Django.